# Strings in a CSV file to initialize a struct

Tags: c

Given a struct:

```
struct Info {
    char name[70];
    char address[120];
    char email[100];
} info[100];
```

How would you transfer a `.csv` file into this structure?

**EXAMPLE**

Take this `.csv` file

```
name,address,email
Carl March,3112 Agriculture Lane,kamir.ezio@ohmyfly.com
Annie Scrims,1773 Sycamore Lake Road,uknheqltodnlrdiwek@kvhrw.com
```

How would you transfer all of this into the `info` structure? The white spaces are causing an issue and using a for loop seems way too clunky.

Comment: "*The white spaces are causing an issue*". Causing an issue for what and in what way? I can probably guess but shouldn't need to. Please show your code as a [mre] and ask a specific question with reference to that code.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `for` loop, use a `while` loop instead.  One or the other is necessary.

Comment: `fgets` to read a line, and `strtok` to separate the fields (using `",\n"` as the delimiter).

Comment: For your sample data, the coding is simple.  If you had a line `"Frederick ""Rick"" Capistrano","67 Acorn Lane ""The Oaks"", Hickville, AN 98765",rick.cap@example.com` with double quotes around strings that themselves contain commas and double quotes, then you would have to work a lot harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `scanf("%s,%s,%s", ...)` you should use `%[^,\n]`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Info {
    char name[70];
    char address[120];
    char email[100];
} info[100];

int main() {
    char buf[1024], eol[2];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 100 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%69[^,\n],%119[^,\n],%99[^,\n]%1[\n]",
            info[i].name, info[i].address, info[i].email, eol) == 4) {
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("invalid record: %s", buf);
        }
    }
    printf("%d records parsed\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this was way easier than I expected. I'm getting into C from C++ and had no clue this was possible in C. Thanks.

Comment: @BertrandDom: this works for simple CSV files. If the fields may contain embedded commas or even if they are just surrounded by double quotes, a more elaborate parser is required.

Comment: Sure, but I have to start somewhere before I think of all the ways issues can occur. This is a very elegant and basic way of doing it, which I can build upon if need be.

Comment: Another shortcoming of this approach is it cannot parse empty fields. And neither would `strtok()`.

Comment: `strtok()` was one of my initial approaches but my unfamiliarity with it lead me to be uncomfortable using it.

Comment: @BertrandDom: you should be. This function is ill conceived in multiple ways.